# WCF self hosted service processing slow compare to same services hosted on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, self-hosting, .net-4.5.2, wcf-configuration

I have a couple of Application which were hosting multiple WCF services.My WCf services also spawn background thread via task parallel library. As we know there is some limits of number of threads and WCF concurrent Calls/instances at a single point of time so I thought hosting inside a self hosted application will improve it. But it have infact negative impact. Around 10,000 transaction processed in 6 odd minutes in IIS takes 12 minutes in self hosted. Any idea what further i need?

Comment: What i done is ported my web.config settings to App.config and hosted the WCF services in my console application. No other code/config changes i have done

Comment: Try using windows service to self host WCF service. If you are using console to do any logging or anything then all those threads are contesting to get access to single resource.

Comment: Ok let me try that.

Comment: Still same behavior